# Mathematica 12.1 integrates functions individually but not their sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I found something odd in MMA 12.1 when symbolically integrating DiracDelta and Piecewise. These functions are integrated individually but not their sum. The following code

```
f[x_] = DiracDelta[x - 12.0];
Integrate[f[x], x]
g[x_] = Piecewise[{{2 x, x < 1}, {4 x, 1 <= x < 2}, {0, True}}];
Integrate[g[x], x]
Integrate[f[x] + g[x], x]
```

produces evaluated integrals in the first two cases but not in the third case. Why?

$$\theta (x-12.)$$

$$\begin{cases}
 x^2 & x\leq 1 \\
 2 x^2-1 & 1<x\leq 2 \\
 7 & \text{True} \\
\end{cases}$$

$$\int \left(\left(
\begin{cases}
 2 x & x<1 \\
 4 x & 1\leq x<2 \\
\end{cases}
\right)+\delta (x-12.)\right) \, dx$$

---

By the way, symbolic Python works as expected.

```
from sympy import *
x=var('x') 
f=DiracDelta(x)
g=Piecewise((1,x<3), (2,x<10),(0,True))
integrate(f+g,x)
```

Comment: I would be super careful about computing indefinite integrals where the integrand is a delta function.  I'm not sure that even makes any sense.  Instead, you should be using definite integrals.  For instance, consider the result of `Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}, Assumptions -> {a < b}]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Distribute[Integrate[f[x] + g[x], x]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that kind of patches the issue. But still I find the behavior of Integrate[...] unusual.

Comment: It probably has to due with the fact that while `g[x]` is piecewise continuous, it is not smooth at the transitions, i.e., it is not differentiable at the transitions. Look at `D[g[x], x].` Consequently, `D[Integrate[g[x], x], x] == g[x] // PiecewiseExpand` is a condition rather than `True`. In the more complicated context, `Integrate` balks.

Comment: I would like to point out that symbolic Python has absolutely no problems with this. `from sympy import *
x=var('x') 
f=DiracDelta(x)
g=Piecewise((1,x<3), (2,x<10),(0,True))
integrate(f+g,x)`